# C# Copy file HTTPClient FTP

Tags: c#, file, ftp, httpclient

I need to copy files from one folder on File System, over FTP protocol to another folder (local or remote).

When I use classic approach with (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create, then I need to mark it as obsolete, because my organization doesn't need and want obsolete code and I'm forced to use HTTPClient. Now, the problem is, I have no idea how to do it, I tried with MultipartFormDataContent, but it says that FTP protocol is not supported.

This is a piece of code that is obsolete and worked:

```
 [Obsolete("Obsolete")]
    private async Task UploadFile(FileDescriptionModel descriptionModel, FtpConfigModel configModel)
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = $"ftp://{configModel.Ip}:{configModel.Port}/{descriptionModel.RelativePath}";
            _logger.LogInformation("Started creating file");
            using var ms = new MemoryStream(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(descriptionModel.FilePath));

            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.ToArray();
            _logger.LogInformation("Started connection to {ipPath}", filePath);
            var ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filePath);
            ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configModel.User, configModel.Password);
            // convert contents to byte.
            await using Stream requestStream = ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            _logger.LogInformation("Started uploading");
            await ms.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
            _logger.LogInformation("Finished uploading");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Stream cannot be read", e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I would need something with HTTPClient, this doesn't work for instance:

```
private async Task<string> UploadFile2(FileDescriptionModel descriptionModel, FtpConfigModel configModel)
    {
        var filePath = $"ftp://{configModel.Ip}:{configModel.Port}/{descriptionModel.RelativePath}";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.SetBasicAuthentication(configModel.User, configModel.Password);
        using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            //Add other fields
            using var ms = new MemoryStream(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(descriptionModel.FilePath));
            multipartFormContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray()),name: "SomeName", fileName: descriptionModel.RelativePath);

            //Send it
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(filePath, multipartFormContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

SOLVED with FluentFTP like this:

````
    private async Task UploadFile3(FileDescriptionModel descriptionModel, FtpConfigModel configModel)
    {
        var client = new AsyncFtpClient(configModel.Ip, configModel.User, configModel.Password,
            configModel.Port);

// connect to the server and automatically detect working FTP settings
        await client.AutoConnect();

// upload a file
        var status = await client.UploadFile(descriptionModel.FilePath, $"{descriptionModel.RelativePath}");

    }```
````

Comment: You cannot use `HTTPClient` for FTP. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I solved it with FluentFTP, my organization has used it already, so the working code is even simpler. Updated question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yeah, but Microsoft is saying otherwise in the comments :)
It says it is deprecated and you must use HTTPClient.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iEml.png

and because of my companies "no obsolete" policy, i cannot use such code.

Comment: Did you notice that the message does not say anything about `FtpWebRequest`? It recommends `HTTPClient` as a replacement for `[Http]WebRequest` and `WebClient`. You [incorrectly] get it for `FtpWebRequest` only because it derives from the `WebRequest`.